# Format-Table not displaying all properties with PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-5.0

With *PowerShell* **V4**, I could use `Format-Table` to display several properties using a wildcard, for instance :

```
PS C:\powershell> gci | Format-Table -Property PS*

PSPath                  PSParentPath           PSChildName            PSDrive                PSProvider                      PSIsContainer
------                  ------------           -----------            -------                ----------                      -------------
Microsoft.PowerShell... Microsoft.PowerShel... test1.txt              C                      Microsoft.PowerShel...                  False
Microsoft.PowerShell... Microsoft.PowerShel... test2.txt              C                      Microsoft.PowerShel...                  False
Microsoft.PowerShell... Microsoft.PowerShel... test3.txt              C                      Microsoft.PowerShel...                  False
```

Now, with *PowerShell* **V5**, I don't get the same result with the same command :

```
PS C:\powershell> gci | Format-Table -Property PS*

PSPath                                                          PSParentPath                                      
------                                                          ------------                                      
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\powershell\test1.txt   Microsoft.PowerShell.Co...
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\powershell\test2.txt   Microsoft.PowerShell.Co...
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\powershell\test3.txt   Microsoft.PowerShell.Co...
```

Only two properties are displayed.

Why is the new behavior and is there a way to change it to the one of V4 ?

Comment: `gci | ft @{expression='ps*'; width=10}`

Comment: Try adding `-AutoSize` to `Format-table`, this will resize the columns as needed to try and fit as many as possible.

Comment: To dynamically change column width and view all properties use `gci|out-gridview *` IIRC `Format-table` by standard limits to 10 columns and even with a small font size these would be shortened to unreadability.

Comment: `Out-GridView` and `Export-Csv` are friendlier than `Format-Table` here.

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell 5 had a change to how columns are auto-sized by default.  It cannot fit the additional columns on the page.  Adding `-AutoSize` will not resolve the issue.

You could increase the side of the window.

Additionally, @PetSerAl's following suggestion will let you specify the width of the columns but you loose auto-sizing.

```
Get-ChildItem | Format-Table -Property @{expression='ps*'; width=10}
```